# Date_Add and Interval error query

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone check my query? It doesn't work well.

the "dateordered" is in varchar the format is 09/10/13

and I think the > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) is the problem I can't find a solution which will convert it to my format.

```
$getdates = "SELECT * FROM tbl_orders WHERE STR_TO_DATE(dateordered, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$currentdate', '%m/%d/%Y') AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)";
$rint =mysql_query($getdates) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rint)) {
print_r($row); 
}
```

The result of this query is "09/10/13" but I have some dates like 09/05/13, 09/01/13, 08/25/13, 08/20/13 and 08/15/13.

Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: Why are you using both `CURDATE()` and `$currentdate` in the `where` clause?  Why is a field called `dateordered` stored as a `varchar()` and not a `date`?

Comment: (don't actually do this) Set `$currentdate` = `'); drop table tbl_orders;`

Comment: I don't know sir I just saw it in google. and it's the only query that gives me so far a result. Is there any way that I can do without changing the the date format?